# $f \in A(U) $ satisfies $ |f(0)| < 1$ and $|f(z)|>1 \forall |z|=1$. Prove f has a fixed point in $D^{0}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | |z| \leq 1 \} \subseteq U $ be the closed unit disk, $U \subseteq \mathbb{C} $ is a domain,
$f \in A(U) $ satisfies $ |f(0)| < 1$ and $|f(z)|>1 \forall |z|=1$. Prove f has a fixed point in $D^{0}$

Obviously if f has some zero in $D^{0}$, then from Rouche’s theorem f(z) and f(z)-z have the same amount of zeroes in D, but i couldnt show f has a zero.

Comment: What's $A(U)$ ?

Comment: Hint: if $f$ has no zero, you can apply the maximum principle to $1/f$ in the unit disk.

Comment: @Mindlack I guess you can put your hint in an anwser ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, I am posting my comment as an answer.

If $f$ has no zero in the open unit disk, then the maximum modulus principle applies to $1/f$ in the open unit disk, and we derive a contradiction.

Then, as suggested by the OP, one can apply Rouché’s theorem to $f(z)$ and $f(z)-z$ for the disk, thus showing $f(z)-z$ must vanish inside the open unit disk, QED.